# ElasticSearch No handler for type [search_as_you_type] declared on field [field_name]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to implement autocomplete with EslasticSearch and I follow search-as-you-type documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-as-you-type.html#search-as-you-type

When I run a mapping query below I get an exception.

```
PUT my-index-000001
 {
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "my_field": {
      "type": "search_as_you_type"
    }
   }
  }
 }

{
 "error": {
 "root_cause": [
   {
     "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
     "reason": "No handler for type [search_as_you_type] declared on field [my_field]"
   }
 ],
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No handler for type [search_as_you_type] declared on field [my_field]",
"caused_by": {
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "No handler for type [search_as_you_type] declared on field [my_field]"
  }
 },
 "status": 400
}
```

Is it documentation providing wrong mapping query or it's me doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET /` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search_as_you_type` type field was introduced in 7.2 version

Since you are using elasticsearch version 5, you are getting the below error

> "reason": "No handler for type [search_as_you_type] declared on field
> [my_field]

Comment: I'm not using ES5, I use ES7.

Comment: @AutoVit which version of ES 7 ? `search_as_you_type` was introduced in 7.2

Comment: I'm using ElasticSearch 7.12

Comment: 7.12 is higher than 7.2? Or I need to use exactly 7.2 version.

Comment: @AutoVit Ohh sorry :/ My bad. I just tested it on 7.10 and it is working fine. Are you sure you are using 7.12 ?

Comment: I just checked and I'm a bit wrong. It's 7.11, but search-as-you-type still should work with this version.

Comment: @AutoVit are you able to create the index? OR is this error coming at the time of index creation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231498/discussion-between-escoder-and-autovit).